# Commenting out or removing an @include from /etc/pam.d/sshd with augtool

Tags: pam, augeas

How can I either comment out or remove the "@include common-auth" line in /etc/pam.d/sshd? The default content is:

```
...

# Standard Un*x authentication.
@include common-auth

...
```

The [lens documentation](http://augeas.net/docs/references/lenses/files/pam-aug.html) isn't all that helpful. I'm new to Augeas and don't quite know how path expressions work yet.

I'm trying to do this with augtool, as part of a Dockerfile, to be specific. I have naively tried the following command, but it didn't work:

```
augtool --autosave 'rm /files/etc/pam.d/sshd/@include common-auth'
```

I resorted to doing this with `sed`, and the following did the job for me:

```
sed -i 's/@include common-auth/#@include common-auth/' /etc/pam.d/sshd
```

But I'm still trying to find out if there's a way to do it with augtool, because I'm doing all the other configuration changes in my Dockerfile using augtool, and uniformity would be nice.

Comment: What have you tried thus far? What worked? What didn't work as expected. Look, we want to help you, but this isn't a script-writing service. We expect that, before getting help here, that you show us what you've tried and give evidence that you've tried to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: @EEAA Couldn't even get to trying much because I don't exactly know what I should be trying. I've tried Googling for documentation. Looked at existing Augeas-related Q&A on Server Fault. I'm asking for pointers to documentation/methods which I couldn't immediately find myself. I'm trying to avoid spending 1 hour reading the entire Augeas documentation to learn about its internals. Not looking for script/code per se.

Comment: Also, you may consider that augtool isn't the right tool for the job. Sometimes standard unix tools like `awk` and `sed` are the right tool.

Comment: I naively tried this, but didn't work: `augtool --autosave 'rm /files/etc/pam.d/sshd/@include common-auth'`

Comment: @EEAA, I totally agree! I can probably just do this with `sed`, but the curious monkey in me is trying to see if there's a way to do this with `augtool`.

Comment: I added the attempted command to the question, and as an Augeas developer I feel there's enough information for me to answer it. Could it be re-opened please?

Comment: @DominicCleal It has been reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing to do when trying to work out which node to edit/delete is to look at the *current* tree using augtool's `print` command:

```
$ augtool
augtool> print /files/etc/pam.d/sshd
/files/etc/pam.d/sshd
/files/etc/pam.d/sshd/#comment[1] = "PAM configuration for the Secure Shell service"
/files/etc/pam.d/sshd/#comment[2] = "Standard Un*x authentication."
/files/etc/pam.d/sshd/include[1] = "common-auth"
/files/etc/pam.d/sshd/#comment[3] = "Disallow non-root logins when /etc/nologin exists."
/files/etc/pam.d/sshd/1
/files/etc/pam.d/sshd/1/type = "account"
[..]
```

This shows that the `@include common-auth` line has the path `/files/etc/pam.d/ssh/include[1]`, so this would delete it:

```
augtool -s 'rm /files/etc/pam.d/sshd/include[1]'
```

Instead of hardcoding the index (1), you can use a path expression to match the value "common-auth", ensuring you delete the correct `@include` entry if it exists.

```
augtool -s 'rm /files/etc/pam.d/sshd/include[. = "common-auth"]'
```

The `.` means the *value* of the node (the right hand side of the `print` output). Anything within the `[]` is a path expression. The [Augeas wiki](https://github.com/hercules-team/augeas/wiki/Path-expressions) has lots more info about path expressions.